# Webview in WorkManager Worker not loading when main application is not open

Tags: android, webview, worker, android-workmanager

I am working on a WorkManager worker for an android application.  One of the functions of the worker is the create a webview, load up the url "file:///" and to run some javascript to pull data from localstroage, indexDB, etc.

Everything works great as long as the main app is open or in the background.  When the app is closed, the worker triggers as expected but the WebView does not load the url consistently.  Out of 4 attempts, the URL usually loads once.  All other times the callback to onPageFinished does not fire.  Has anyone seen this before?  My code is below:

**createWorker()**

```
  public static void createWorker() {

   Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();

    PeriodicWorkRequest notificationWork =
            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationHandler.class, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                    .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("LC_NoteService", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, notificationWork);

}
```

**doWork()**

```
public Result doWork() {


    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    try
    {
        handler.post(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        WebView myWebView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
                        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                            @Override
                            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
                            {
                                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                                Log.d("TAG", "Inside onPageFinish");

                                myWebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() {\n" +
                                        "SOME JAVASCRIPT HERE" +
                                        "})();", new ValueCallback<String>() {

                                    @Override public void onReceiveValue(String s) {

                                        loopBack(); //function for checking data
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errCode, String desc, String failingURL)
                            {
                                Log.d("TAG", "WebView Error Code: " + errCode + " Description: " + desc + " URL: " + failingURL);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                                view.loadUrl(url);
                                return true;
                            }
                            public void loopBack()
                            {
                                //SOME LOGIC

                            }
                        });

                        Log.d("TAG", "About to Create Set Webview Settings");
                        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
                        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
                        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
                        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
                        myWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + myWebView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
                        myWebView.loadUrl("file://");

                   }
                }
        );
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Result.success();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Minimum time interval for Periodic Work Request is 15 minutes. You have set it to 30 seconds. This may result in change inn desired behaviour